# Java NoClassDefFoundError for the InnerClass

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am trying to execute a Java class from ant. I first create a jar file for my class and then execute it via ant target. But it is throwing me this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/abc/utils/ClassName$InnerClass

I am creating a jar in the build file like this:

```
<jar destfile="${dist.dir}/../lib/jarFile.jar" basedir="${basedir}/classes" includes="com/abc/utils/ClassName.class" />
```

If I remove the "includes" during the creating of the jar, then everything is fine and I am able to execute the jar file, but I don't want to include all the files in the jar, since I only need this one class.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That inner class will be a separate file (called `ClassName$InnerClass.class`, I think), and you're explicitly *excluding* it in your jar definition.

Inner classes will manifest themselves as separate class files in the filesystem. Hence just including that one .class file unfortunately will break your deployable, as it's missing the corresponding inner class.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using an inner class in class `ClassName`. This will produce a *separate* class file.

Because you're using the `includes` attribute, the `jar` task is specifically only including a single class file: `ClassName.class`. Remove the `includes`, and all class files will end up in your jar.

Note that `includes/excludes` will also accept a comma-separated or space-separated list, e.g.:

```
<jar destfile="${dist.dir}/../lib/jarFile.jar" basedir="${basedir}/classes" includes="com/abc/utils/ClassName.class,com/abc/utils/ClassName$InnerClass.class" />
```

This or a similar list should address your issue if you want to only include `ClassName` and any inner classes or additional dependencies in the jar.

Answer (score 1):

If it is inner class, may be you need to do `enclosingclass$className.class` because your innerclass will be created in separate file with $ symbol appended.

Note: If another class depend on this class, runtime you may see issues.